# asp.net vnext display name can't display

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My model is

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name222")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

My view is

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
```

It's display "**UserName**"，not "**User name222**".

And the ErrorMessage display "**The User name222 field is required.**"

==============================================
All the code is VS14 CTP2 Asp.net Vnext Web Application automatic generation.

Why?How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

UserName is the Propoerty which you want the controller to know the property by that name , Dispaly Method will set your property to that Name .assign some value to the Property UserName in a Constructor like.

public class RegisterViewModel

```
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public RegisterViewModel(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        model.UserName = "user 123";
        this.UserName = model.UserName;
    }
}
```

and here when you are calling in your view please use the "null" parameter in html helper as 
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName,null, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })

Comment: It also display "UserName",not"User name222" or "user 123"

Comment: @user3339775 can you please share your Controller and how you reference model in your view.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is being [tracked](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/532) and it is being addressed as we speak.

Thanks,
Kirthi